How do I copy the generalized Windows 10 .wim file from virtualmachine?
I'm currently creating a custom Windows 10 ISO that I want to install on several different machines.
I started working on it in VirtualBox. I installed Windows 10 and put it into Audit mode. I installed the necessary applications and made a few configurations. I installed ADK to create an answer file for the automated installation. Additionally, I made a WinPE ISO. After this, I ran Sysprep.
The final goal is to copy the .wim file and create a custom ISO.
My question is, how can I use the WinPE ISO instead of Windows in VirtualBox? After that, I’d like to copy the .wim file somewhere, but I’m having trouble connecting a flash drive so it automatically becomes part of the virtual machine.
Thanks for the help.
